# Blocking vs. nonblocking UDP socket for single host

Tags: c, sockets, udp, nonblocking, latency

I am writing a client that receives UDP datagrams from a single sender.  All IO will be done in a single thread.  Generally, there will either be no data, or a 30 MBit/s stream.  My primary concern is in keeping latency as low as possible.

The plan is to block, waiting for data, in a loop with a short-ish timeout, so that the IO thread can be responsive to shutdown requests, etc.

I am inclined to use a blocking socket, set a timeout on it, and do a `recvfrom()` call.  However, this seems to be much less common than a `select()`/`poll()` and `recvfrom()` combination on a nonblocking socket.

Given that I am only working with a single socket, it seems that the nonblocking approach is needlessly complicated.  Am I missing something else?  Is there a reason to prefer nonblocking sockets in this particular case?

Comment: You don't even need a timeout - you can send a signal to your receiving thread to cause `recvfrom()` to return immediately with `errno == EINTR`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a dedicated thread for handling the socket then asynchronous I/O, `select` etc are useless. What you want is simply `recvfrom(2)` and handle the data as quickly as possible.

Any fancy mechanisms (`epoll`, `libaio`, etc.) won't help you get more speed out of your application.

Comment: True, they don't help you get more speed, but they do help you scale.  Eventually, you might scale enough to allow for more throughput.  It's a good time to remember that speed != throughput.

Comment: @Edwin: `select` and its ilk do not help you scale a UDP server which only ever has one socket.

Answer (score 3):

With only a  few peers, (and 'one' is surely in this set:), a thread with a blocking socket should be fine.  The code is easier to write since state can be maintained in the dedicated thread - no need for the state-machines that are usually required with a non-blocking system.

Short timeout - do you need this? Do you shutdown this subsystem before app close?  If not, could you just let it be killed by OS?

If you have to shut down the thread system, you could set some 'terminate' flag and send yourself a UDP message to unblock the thread so it realises it has to die.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Oh... right... connectionless protocols make stuff like sending terminating packets easy.  Of course.  I like that.  Thanks.

Comment: Darn, I've been looking for a way to terminate my blocking receiving thread on command for a while and I didn't even think about sending myself a packet. This is a great workaround, thanks.